# Java: ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

This is my arraylist method from a class called ants, it is made to store objects such as nests,food and obstacles.

```
public ArrayList<Cell> getObstacles() {
    ArrayList<Cell> obstacles = new ArrayList<Cell>();
      for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                Cell currentcell = cellArray[columns][rows];
              // Initialize each object
              if(currentcell.isBlocked()){
                  obstacles.add(currentcell);
              }
              else if(currentcell.isGoal()){
                  obstacles.add(currentcell);
              }
              else if(currentcell.hasNest()){
                  obstacles.add(currentcell);
              }
            }
          }
        return obstacles;
        }
```

When i retrieve my arraylist and use it in the method from another class called antscontrolpanel, there is an error-arrayindexoutofboundexception. Does anyone know how to solve this error?

```
public void savemap (File file)
      {
          ArrayList<Cell> obstacles = ants.getObstacles();

    if (file == null) {         
      if (chooser == null) chooser = createChooser();
      chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);
      int r = chooser.showDialog(this, null);
      if (r != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) return;
      file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    }

    /**
     * For obstacles added to the program:
     * Simple parsing of relevant data into txt file for easy reading.
     * Rows will be written like so:
     * 
     * 50 25 b
     * 51 25 b
     * 52 25 b
     * 34 28 n
     * .
     * .
     * 
     * Column, followed by row, followed by type of obstacle.
     * Assumption: Only one obstacle per cell. Should be a relatively simple extension for multiple obstacles per cell.
     */

    try {

        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(file), "utf-8"));
        for(int i = 0; i < obstacles.size(); i++)
        {
            Cell currentCell = obstacles.get(i);
            writer.write(Integer.toString(currentCell.c));
            writer.write(" ");
            writer.write(Integer.toString(currentCell.r));
            writer.write(" ");

            if(currentCell.isBlocked())
                writer.write(blockedChar);
            else if(currentCell.isGoal())
                writer.write(goalChar);
            else if(currentCell.hasNest())
                writer.write(nestChar);
            writer.write("\n");

        }

        writer.close();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
      String msg = e.getMessage();
      this.stat.setText(msg); System.err.println(msg);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, msg,
        "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }                           /* set the status text */
    this.curr = file;          
  }
```

Comment: You need to provide the stacktrace so that we could help you debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your indices are `rows` and `indices` instead of `i` and `j`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Cell currentcell = cellArray[columns][rows];
```

Wrong indices. You should be using `cellArray[i][j]`. This line should have been specifically pointed out to you by the error message.